# testcases not running for app using same name as django contrib app

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've just realized that I named my django app `myproject.sites` which is the same name as the built-in django app, `'django.contrib.sites'`. (both are in `INSTALLED_APPS`)

I just finished writing testcases for it, and found that they won't run when I try to run thet tests:

```
manage.py test sites
```

Instead seems to run `'django.contrib.sites'`, instead of `myproject.sites`.

Am I stuck renaming my app and refactoring all my code, or is there a way I can run the tests created for `myproject.sites`?

(maybe it'll run if I just run all tests?  Haven't tried yet since it takes a long time to run the full suite for my app...)

Comment: have you tried manage.py test myproject.sites ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix, just put your `myproject.sites` higher in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` than the `django.contrib.sites`.  The default test runner will pick the first app name that matches from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

For larger projects, I much prefer to use the additional power of [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) which will allow fine-grained control over which tests are run.